# can't set xlabel and ylabel in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to matplotlib and I can't set the axis labels for my plot.
I also tried plt.xlabel("xlabel") and ax1.set(xlabel="Images") but both have failed. Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig.suptitle("Cross Entropy Loss", fontsize=20)

ax1.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel')

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("loss1.txt", "r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            x, y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar, yar)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.title("Cross Entropy Loss")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax1.clear()` clears the subplot including the labels. You could, for example move `ax1.set_xlabel('xlabel')` and `ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel')` to after `ax1.clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearing your axes when doing "ax1.clear()", for that reason "ax1.set_xlabel('xlabel')" and "ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel')" are not showing what you want.

To solve this simply put both "set_x_label" and "set_y_label" **after** clearing ax1.
The code should resemble the following:

```
...
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            x, y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xlabel('xlabel')
    ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel')
    ax1.plot(xar, yar)
...
```